# What's the difference between an embryo and a fetus?

Tags: embryology

The most I've been able to come up with is that fetuses are embryos slightly farther along in their development. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You can read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embryo) about an embryo:

> An embryo is a multicellular diploid eukaryote in its earliest stage of development, from the >time of first cell division until birth, hatching, or germination. In humans, it is called an >embryo until about eight weeks after fertilization (i.e. ten weeks after the last menstrual >period or LMP), and from then it is instead called a fetus.